# vaadin 7: layout displaced after opening/closing dialog window

Tags: layout, vaadin

I am new to the forum and to programming so hopefully I give you enough details and precise information needed to understand my question.

I am working with vaadin 7 in java EE web aplication and I have a layout problem/phanomena that I cannot explain and I could not find a solution on the net. Basically, when I start the server and test my application on localhost everything looks right. When I open a dialogue window and close it again, the layout of the site looks displaced. I could not find a pattern as to which click causes this effect. Sometimes it happens also when I only change a view. This is [how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2IRv.png) and this is [how it does look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3weEB.png) after working in the application.

I looked through the devloper tool in the browser and noticed that in the working html, the attributes "top" and "left" are set for the gridlayout-slot. In the displaced layout these attributes are not set. Furthermore, it seems that the problem occurs more often in chrome. It does also happen in firefox but less often.

I use VerticalLayout, GridLayout and FormLayout.

Did you have similar experience? I am wondering how and when the html files are generated from the vaadin code to find out why they change and how I can fix it.

I am not sure which code exactly is causing the problem, so I am not sure what to post. If you have an idea where to look, I can add more code. Here is how the Dialog is set up:

```
public class Dialog extends Window implements ClickListener

public Dialog(CustomController controller, String title)
  {
    super(title);
    setModal(true);
    setStyleName("dialogWindow");

    this.controller = controller;
    setWidth("65.0%");
    setHeight("90.0%");

    // top level component properties
    panLayout = new GridLayout();
    panLayout.setWidth("100%");
    panLayout.setHeight("100%");

    buildPanToolbar();
    panLayout.addComponent(panToolbar);

    buildPanTop();
    panLayout.addComponent(panTop);

    buildPanTabs();
    panLayout.addComponent(tabsheet);
    panLayout.setComponentAlignment(tabsheet, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    panLayout.setRowExpandRatio(2, 1.0f);

    tfThema.focus();

    setContent(panLayout);

  }
```

The `buildSomething()` functions are all a combination of GridLayout, FormLayout, HorizontalLayout and VerticalLayout. Below is the `buildPanToolbar()` function as an example

```
  private void buildPanToolbar()
  {
    panToolbar = new HorizontalLayout();
    panToolbar.setImmediate(false);
    panToolbar.setWidth("100%");
    panToolbar.setHeight("25px");
    panToolbar.setMargin(false);
    panToolbar.setSpacing(true);
    panToolbar.setStyleName("toolbar");

    HorizontalLayout panHelpToolbar = new HorizontalLayout();
    panHelpToolbar.setImmediate(false);
    panHelpToolbar.setWidth("-1px");
    panHelpToolbar.setHeight("25px");
    panHelpToolbar.setMargin(false);
    panHelpToolbar.setSpacing(true);
    panHelpToolbar.setStyleName("toolbarButtons");
    panToolbar.addComponent(panHelpToolbar);


    pbButton1 = new Button();
    pbButton1.setCaption("Button1Text");
    pbButton1.setStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
    pbButton1.setImmediate(true);
    pbButton1.setWidth("100px");
    pbButton1.setHeight("-1px");
    pbButton1.setIcon(new ThemeResource("../images/pic1.gif"));
    pbButton1.addClickListener(controller);
    panHelpToolbar.addComponent(pbButton1);
    panHelpToolbar.setComponentAlignment(pbButton1, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);

    pbButton2= new Button();
    pbButton2.setCaption("Button2 Text");
    pbButton2.setImmediate(true);
    pbButton2.setWidth("100%");
    pbButton2.setHeight("-1px");
    pbButton2.setStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
    pbButton2.setIcon(new ThemeResource("../images/pic.gif"));
    pbButton2.addClickListener(this);

    panHelpToolbar.addComponent(pbButton2);
    panHelpToolbar.setComponentAlignment(pbButton2, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);

  }
```

Comment: Please show the code you have to generate the screens/dialoges http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you Andre. I wasnt sure which code would be helpful. Now I added an example of how the dialog is set up. Please let me know if you were looking for something different. The screens follow a similar style.